# mIRC Execute command after X lines of chat

Tags: timer, message, bots, irc, mirc

I'm a selflearned mIRC programmer and started very recently so my experience is quite limited. Here's the problem I have:

I'm creating a chat bot for Twitch and have created besides a raffle system a timed message for promting the stream it's on every few minutes. However, I'd also like to repeat the message after X lines of chat lines sent in the chat in-case the chat is going quickly so you don't miss out on social links and stuff for new visitors.

Pseudo-code for what I want to be done:

```
on !startpromote
  if (broadcaster) then PromoteMessage every X amount of lines passed
  else return
end
on !stoppromote
  if (broadcaster) then PromoteMessage stop
  else return
end
```

Comment: If actually read the whole post you'd notice I do ask for something. An explicit question mark is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `%msgCounter` variable in the `variables tab` and then you could use the `TEXT` event:

```
on *:TEXT:#:{
  INC %msgCounter
  if (%msgCounter > 10) { msg $chan Promotion message. }
}
```

You'd have to keep track of the `%msgCounter` variable and reset it when it hits a certain threshold.

Not sure what you mean by broadcaster, however if you mean `IRCOp` than you can use `isop` and do:

```
if ($1 isop $chan) {

}
```

Where `$1` is the user who typed the message, `isop` determines if the user is an operator (or maybe broadcaster) and `$chan` for the IRC Channel.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted! :)